# Spring Security redirect to previous page after successful login

Tags: spring, redirect, authentication, spring-security

I know this question has been asked before, however I'm facing a particular issue here.

I use spring security 3.1.3.

I have 3 possible login cases in my web application:

1. Login via the login page : OK.
2. Login via a restricted page : OK too.
3. Login via a non-restricted page : not OK... a "product" page can be accessed by everybody, and a user can post a comment if he's logged. So a login form is contained in the same page in order to allow users to connect.

The problem with case 3) is that I can't manage to redirect users to the "product" page. They get redirected to the home page after a successful login, no matter what.

Notice that with case 2) the redirection to the restricted page works out of the box after successful login.

Here's the relevant part of my security.xml file:

```
<!-- Authentication policy for the restricted page  -->
<http use-expressions="true" auto-config="true" pattern="/restrictedPage/**">
    <form-login login-page="/login/restrictedLogin" authentication-failure-handler-ref="authenticationFailureHandler" />
    <intercept-url pattern="/**" access="isAuthenticated()" />
</http>

<!-- Authentication policy for every page -->
<http use-expressions="true" auto-config="true">
    <form-login login-page="/login" authentication-failure-handler-ref="authenticationFailureHandler" />
    <logout logout-url="/logout" logout-success-url="/" />
</http>
```

I suspect the "authentication policy for every page" to be responsible for the problem. However, if I remove it I can't login anymore... j_spring_security_check sends a 404 error.

---

EDIT:

Thanks to Ralph, I was able to find a solution. So here's the thing: I used the property

```
<property name="useReferer" value="true"/>
```

that Ralph showed me. After that I had a problem with my case 1) : when logging via the login page, the user stayed in the same page (and not redirected to the home page, like it used to be). The code until this stage was the following:

```
<!-- Authentication policy for login page -->
<http use-expressions="true" auto-config="true" pattern="/login/**">
    <form-login login-page="/login" authentication-success-handler-ref="authenticationSuccessHandlerWithoutReferer" />
</http>

<!-- Authentication policy for every page -->
<http use-expressions="true" auto-config="true">
    <form-login login-page="/login" authentication-failure-handler-ref="authenticationFailureHandler" />
    <logout logout-url="/logout" logout-success-url="/" authentication-success-handler-ref="authenticationSuccessHandler"/>
</http>

<beans:bean id="authenticationSuccessHandler" class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.SavedRequestAwareAuthenticationSuccessHandler">
    <!-- After login, return to the last visited page -->
    <beans:property name="useReferer" value="true" />
</beans:bean>

<beans:bean id="authenticationSuccessHandlerWithoutReferer" class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.SavedRequestAwareAuthenticationSuccessHandler">
    <!-- After login, stay to the same page -->
    <beans:property name="useReferer" value="false" />
</beans:bean>
```

This should work, in theory at least, but it wasn't. I still dont know why, so if someone has an answer on this, I will gladly create a new topic to allo him to share his solution.

In the meantime, I came to a workaround. Not the best solution, but like I said, if someone has something better to show, I'm all ears. So this is the new authentication policy for the login page :

```
<http use-expressions="true" auto-config="true" pattern="/login/**" >
    <intercept-url pattern="/**" access="isAnonymous()" />
    <access-denied-handler error-page="/"/>
</http>
```

The solution here is pretty obvious: the login page is allowed only for anonymous users. Once a user is connected, the error handler redirects him to the home page.

I did some tests, and everything seems to be working nicely.

Comment: you can use the url used in the namespace configuration to find out more info about all the available attributes for a bean, for spring security (3.1) see http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.1.xsd

Answer (score 52, accepted):

What happens after login (to which url the user is redirected) is handled by the `AuthenticationSuccessHandler`.

This interface (a concrete class implementing  it is `SavedRequestAwareAuthenticationSuccessHandler`) is invoked by the `AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter` or one of its subclasses like (`UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter`) in the method `successfulAuthentication`.

So in order to have an other redirect in case 3 you have to subclass `SavedRequestAwareAuthenticationSuccessHandler` and make it to do what you want.

---

Sometimes (depending on your exact usecase) it is enough to enable the `useReferer` flag of `AbstractAuthenticationTargetUrlRequestHandler` which is invoked by `SimpleUrlAuthenticationSuccessHandler` (super class of `SavedRequestAwareAuthenticationSuccessHandler`).

```
<bean id="authenticationFilter"
      class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter">
    <property name="filterProcessesUrl" value="/login/j_spring_security_check" />
    <property name="authenticationManager" ref="authenticationManager" />
    <property name="authenticationSuccessHandler">
        <bean class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.SavedRequestAwareAuthenticationSuccessHandler">
            <property name="useReferer" value="true"/>
        </bean>
    </property>
    <property name="authenticationFailureHandler">
        <bean class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.SimpleUrlAuthenticationFailureHandler">
            <property name="defaultFailureUrl" value="/login?login_error=t" />
        </bean>
    </property>
</bean>
```

Comment: There's no possibility to use entirely xml configuration ? And how do I manage to store the last visited page ?

Comment: You mean that you do not want to create a subclass of the `SavedRequestAwareAuthenticationSuccessHandler`?

Comment: Yes if possible. However, if it's not possible, could you provide an implementation example ?

Comment: @Christos Loupassakis extending `SavedRequestAwareAuthenticationSuccessHandler` should be very easy, the `onAuthenticationSuccess` mehtod only 30 lines long, so have a look at the code.

Comment: @Christos Loupassakis: but maybe the useReferer attribute is what you need - see my extended answer

Comment: Thanks ! useReferer is exactly what I need ! Now my case 3) works fine but... case 1) does not work anymore : when I login from the login page, I stay in the login page (I used to be redirected to home page). Even if I specify a "authentication-success-handler-ref" for my login page with "useReferer = false" the result is the same. This is giving me headaches. Anyway, I'm looking forward to this problem and I'll validate your answer soon, even if I can't manage that (it looks like a different matter).

Comment: After digging a lot, it seems that the embedded login form in case 3) is the problem. In my initial configuration (without "useReferer") if a restrict the whole "product" page, after login the redirection is successful. But this page can't be restricted, it's a public page where users can login among other things. That's really troublesome, I wonder if spring security just can't handle this case (which seems a pretty common case to me anyway ! same applies on stackoverflow for example !) or if it's me doing it wrong.

Comment: Ok I found a workaround ! It's more a "quick-and-dirty" solution, but for now it works. I'll edit my original post to show it. If any idea on how to get it better, I'm all ears :) In the meantime, I valid your answer.

Answer (score 49):

I want to extend **Olcay**'s nice answer. His approach is good, your login page controller should be like this to put the referrer url into session:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/login", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String loginPage(HttpServletRequest request, Model model) {
    String referrer = request.getHeader("Referer");
    request.getSession().setAttribute("url_prior_login", referrer);
    // some other stuff
    return "login";
}
```

And you should extend `SavedRequestAwareAuthenticationSuccessHandler` and override its `onAuthenticationSuccess(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Authentication authentication)` method. Something like this:

```
public class MyCustomLoginSuccessHandler extends SavedRequestAwareAuthenticationSuccessHandler {
    public MyCustomLoginSuccessHandler(String defaultTargetUrl) {
        setDefaultTargetUrl(defaultTargetUrl);
    }

    @Override
    public void onAuthenticationSuccess(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Authentication authentication) throws ServletException, IOException {
        HttpSession session = request.getSession();
        if (session != null) {
            String redirectUrl = (String) session.getAttribute("url_prior_login");
            if (redirectUrl != null) {
                // we do not forget to clean this attribute from session
                session.removeAttribute("url_prior_login");
                // then we redirect
                getRedirectStrategy().sendRedirect(request, response, redirectUrl);
            } else {
                super.onAuthenticationSuccess(request, response, authentication);
            }
        } else {
            super.onAuthenticationSuccess(request, response, authentication);
        }
    }
}
```

Then, in your spring configuration, you should define this custom class as a bean and use it on your security configuration. If you are using **annotation config**, it should look like this (the class you extend from `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter`):

```
@Bean
public AuthenticationSuccessHandler successHandler() {
    return new MyCustomLoginSuccessHandler("/yourdefaultsuccessurl");
}
```

In `configure` method:

```
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
            // bla bla
            .formLogin()
                .loginPage("/login")
                .usernameParameter("username")
                .passwordParameter("password")
                .successHandler(successHandler())
                .permitAll()
            // etc etc
    ;
}
```

Comment: This was a great idea thanks for completing the answer, and in your `onAuthenticationSuccess` session will never be null so no need to check that `.getSession()` will never return null

Comment: Thank you for this answer.  It helped.  However, I'm trying to add a cookie containing a JWT to the response.  Looks like it is adding that cookie to the response for `/j_spring_security_check`, but not for the response to the redirect.

Answer (score 8):

I have following solution and it worked for me.

Whenever login page is requested, write the referer value to the session:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/login", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String login(ModelMap model,HttpServletRequest request) {

    String referrer = request.getHeader("Referer");
    if(referrer!=null){
        request.getSession().setAttribute("url_prior_login", referrer);
    }
    return "user/login";
}
```

Then, after successful login custom implementation of `SavedRequestAwareAuthenticationSuccessHandler` will redirect user to the previous page:

```
HttpSession session = request.getSession(false);
if (session != null) {
    url = (String) request.getSession().getAttribute("url_prior_login");
}
```

Redirect the user:

```
if (url != null) {
    response.sendRedirect(url);
}
```

Comment: only url without query param

Comment: this one will better https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33368963/how-to-get-all-session-values-and-names/51794874

Answer (score 2):

I've custom OAuth2 authorization and `request.getHeader("Referer")` is not available at poit of decision. But security request already saved in `ExceptionTranslationFilter.sendStartAuthentication`:

```
protected void sendStartAuthentication(HttpServletRequest request,...
    ...
    requestCache.saveRequest(request, response);
```

So, all what we need is share `requestCache` as Spring bean:

```
@Bean
public RequestCache requestCache() {
   return new HttpSessionRequestCache();
}

@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
   http.authorizeRequests()
   ... 
   .requestCache().requestCache(requestCache()).and()
   ...
}
```

and use it wheen authorization is finished:

```
@Autowired
private RequestCache requestCache;

public void authenticate(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp){
    ....
    SavedRequest savedRequest = requestCache.getRequest(req, resp);
    resp.sendRedirect(savedRequest != null && "GET".equals(savedRequest.getMethod()) ?  
    savedRequest.getRedirectUrl() : "defaultURL");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The following generic solution can be used with regular login, a Spring Social login, or most other Spring Security filters.

In your Spring MVC controller, when loading the product page, save the path to the product page in the session if user has not been logged in. In XML config, set the default target url. For example:

In your Spring MVC controller, the redirect method should read out the path from the session and return `redirect:<my_saved_product_path>`.

So, after user logs in, they'll be sent to `/redirect` page, which will promptly redirect them back to the product page that they last visited.

Answer (score 0):

Back to previous page after succesfull login, we can use following custom authentication manager as follows:

```
<!-- enable use-expressions -->
    <http auto-config="true" use-expressions="true">
        <!-- src** matches: src/bar.c src/baz.c src/test/bartest.c-->
        <intercept-url pattern="/problemSolution/home/**" access="hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')"/>
        <intercept-url pattern="favicon.ico" access="permitAll"/>
        <form-login
                authentication-success-handler-ref="authenticationSuccessHandler"
                always-use-default-target="true"
                login-processing-url="/checkUser"
                login-page="/problemSolution/index"

                default-target-url="/problemSolution/home"
                authentication-failure-url="/problemSolution/index?error"
                username-parameter="username"
                password-parameter="password"/>
        <logout logout-url="/problemSolution/logout"
                logout-success-url="/problemSolution/index?logout"/>
        <!-- enable csrf protection -->
        <csrf/>
    </http>

    <beans:bean id="authenticationSuccessHandler"
            class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.SavedRequestAwareAuthenticationSuccessHandler">
        <beans:property name="defaultTargetUrl" value="/problemSolution/home"/>
    </beans:bean>

    <!-- Select users and user_roles from database -->
    <authentication-manager>
        <authentication-provider user-service-ref="customUserDetailsService">
            <password-encoder hash="plaintext">
            </password-encoder>
        </authentication-provider>
    </authentication-manager>
```

CustomUserDetailsService class

```
@Service
public class CustomUserDetailsService implements UserDetailsService {

        @Autowired
        private UserService userService;

        public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String userName)
                        throws UsernameNotFoundException {
                com.codesenior.telif.local.model.User domainUser = userService.getUser(userName);

                boolean enabled = true;
                boolean accountNonExpired = true;
                boolean credentialsNonExpired = true;
                boolean accountNonLocked = true;

                return new User(
                                domainUser.getUsername(),
                                domainUser.getPassword(),
                                enabled,
                                accountNonExpired,
                                credentialsNonExpired,
                                accountNonLocked,
                                getAuthorities(domainUser.getUserRoleList())
                );
        }

        public Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> getAuthorities(List<UserRole> userRoleList) {
                return getGrantedAuthorities(getRoles(userRoleList));
        }

        public List<String> getRoles(List<UserRole> userRoleList) {

                List<String> roles = new ArrayList<String>();

                for(UserRole userRole:userRoleList){
                        roles.add(userRole.getRole());
                }
                return roles;
        }

        public static List<GrantedAuthority> getGrantedAuthorities(List<String> roles) {
                List<GrantedAuthority> authorities = new ArrayList<GrantedAuthority>();

                for (String role : roles) {
                        authorities.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority(role));
                }
                return authorities;
        }

}
```

User Class

```
import com.codesenior.telif.local.model.UserRole;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.security.core.GrantedAuthority;
import org.springframework.security.core.authority.SimpleGrantedAuthority;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetails;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UsernameNotFoundException;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.List;


@Service
public class CustomUserDetailsService implements UserDetailsService {

        @Autowired
        private UserService userService;

        public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String userName)
                        throws UsernameNotFoundException {
                com.codesenior.telif.local.model.User domainUser = userService.getUser(userName);

                boolean enabled = true;
                boolean accountNonExpired = true;
                boolean credentialsNonExpired = true;
                boolean accountNonLocked = true;

                return new User(
                                domainUser.getUsername(),
                                domainUser.getPassword(),
                                enabled,
                                accountNonExpired,
                                credentialsNonExpired,
                                accountNonLocked,
                                getAuthorities(domainUser.getUserRoleList())
                );
        }

        public Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> getAuthorities(List<UserRole> userRoleList) {
                return getGrantedAuthorities(getRoles(userRoleList));
        }

        public List<String> getRoles(List<UserRole> userRoleList) {

                List<String> roles = new ArrayList<String>();

                for(UserRole userRole:userRoleList){
                        roles.add(userRole.getRole());
                }
                return roles;
        }

        public static List<GrantedAuthority> getGrantedAuthorities(List<String> roles) {
                List<GrantedAuthority> authorities = new ArrayList<GrantedAuthority>();

                for (String role : roles) {
                        authorities.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority(role));
                }
                return authorities;
        }

}
```

UserRole Class

```
@Entity
public class UserRole {
        @Id
        @GeneratedValue
        private Integer userRoleId;

        private String role;

        @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "userRoleList")
        @JsonIgnore
        private List<User> userList;

        public Integer getUserRoleId() {
                return userRoleId;
        }

        public void setUserRoleId(Integer userRoleId) {
                this.userRoleId= userRoleId;
        }

        public String getRole() {
                return role;
        }

        public void setRole(String role) {
                this.role= role;
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
                return String.valueOf(userRoleId);
        }

        public List<User> getUserList() {
                return userList;
        }

        public void setUserList(List<User> userList) {
                this.userList= userList;
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a Custom SuccessHandler extending SimpleUrlAuthenticationSuccessHandler for redirecting users to different URLs when login according to their assigned roles.

CustomSuccessHandler class provides custom redirect functionality:

```
package com.mycompany.uomrmsweb.configuration;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.List;

import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

import org.springframework.security.core.Authentication;
import org.springframework.security.core.GrantedAuthority;
import org.springframework.security.web.DefaultRedirectStrategy;
import org.springframework.security.web.RedirectStrategy;
import org.springframework.security.web.authentication.SimpleUrlAuthenticationSuccessHandler;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component
public class CustomSuccessHandler extends SimpleUrlAuthenticationSuccessHandler{

    private RedirectStrategy redirectStrategy = new DefaultRedirectStrategy();

    @Override
    protected void handle(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Authentication authentication) throws IOException {
        String targetUrl = determineTargetUrl(authentication);

        if (response.isCommitted()) {
            System.out.println("Can't redirect");
            return;
        }

        redirectStrategy.sendRedirect(request, response, targetUrl);
    }

    protected String determineTargetUrl(Authentication authentication) {
        String url="";

        Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> authorities =  authentication.getAuthorities();

        List<String> roles = new ArrayList<String>();

        for (GrantedAuthority a : authorities) {
            roles.add(a.getAuthority());
        }

        if (isStaff(roles)) {
            url = "/staff";
        } else if (isAdmin(roles)) {
            url = "/admin";
        } else if (isStudent(roles)) {
            url = "/student";
        }else if (isUser(roles)) {
            url = "/home";
        } else {
            url="/Access_Denied";
        }

        return url;
    }

    public void setRedirectStrategy(RedirectStrategy redirectStrategy) {
        this.redirectStrategy = redirectStrategy;
    }
    protected RedirectStrategy getRedirectStrategy() {
        return redirectStrategy;
    }

    private boolean isUser(List<String> roles) {
        if (roles.contains("ROLE_USER")) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    private boolean isStudent(List<String> roles) {
        if (roles.contains("ROLE_Student")) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    private boolean isAdmin(List<String> roles) {
        if (roles.contains("ROLE_SystemAdmin") || roles.contains("ROLE_ExaminationsStaff")) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    private boolean isStaff(List<String> roles) {
        if (roles.contains("ROLE_AcademicStaff") || roles.contains("ROLE_UniversityAdmin")) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

Extending Spring SimpleUrlAuthenticationSuccessHandler class and overriding handle() method which simply invokes a redirect using configured RedirectStrategy [default in this case] with the URL returned by the user defined determineTargetUrl() method. This method extracts the Roles of currently logged in user from Authentication object and then construct appropriate URL based on there roles. Finally RedirectStrategy , which is responsible for all redirections within Spring Security framework , redirects the request to specified URL.

Registering CustomSuccessHandler using SecurityConfiguration class:

```
package com.mycompany.uomrmsweb.configuration;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.builders.AuthenticationManagerBuilder;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService;

@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("customUserDetailsService")
    UserDetailsService userDetailsService;

    @Autowired
    CustomSuccessHandler customSuccessHandler;

    @Autowired
    public void configureGlobalSecurity(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
            auth.userDetailsService(userDetailsService);
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.authorizeRequests()
        .antMatchers("/", "/home").access("hasRole('USER')")
        .antMatchers("/admin/**").access("hasRole('SystemAdmin') or hasRole('ExaminationsStaff')")
        .antMatchers("/staff/**").access("hasRole('AcademicStaff') or hasRole('UniversityAdmin')")
        .antMatchers("/student/**").access("hasRole('Student')")  
                    .and().formLogin().loginPage("/login").successHandler(customSuccessHandler)
        .usernameParameter("username").passwordParameter("password")
        .and().csrf()
        .and().exceptionHandling().accessDeniedPage("/Access_Denied");
    }
}
```

successHandler is the class responsible for eventual redirection based on any custom logic, which in this case will be to redirect the user [to student/admin/staff ] based on his role [USER/Student/SystemAdmin/UniversityAdmin/ExaminationsStaff/AcademicStaff].

Answer (score 0):

I found [Utku Özdemir's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23796392/6448518) works to some extent, but kind of defeats the purpose of the saved request since the session attribute will take precedence over it. This means that redirects to secure pages will not work as intended - after login you will be sent to the page you were on instead of the redirect target. So as an alternative you could use a modified version of SavedRequestAwareAuthenticationSuccessHandler instead of extending it. This will allow you to have better control over when to use the session attribute.

Here is an example:

```
private static class MyCustomLoginSuccessHandler extends SimpleUrlAuthenticationSuccessHandler {

    private RequestCache requestCache = new HttpSessionRequestCache();

    @Override
    public void onAuthenticationSuccess(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response,
            Authentication authentication) throws ServletException, IOException {
        SavedRequest savedRequest = requestCache.getRequest(request, response);

        if (savedRequest == null) {
            HttpSession session = request.getSession();
            if (session != null) {
                String redirectUrl = (String) session.getAttribute("url_prior_login");
                if (redirectUrl != null) {
                    session.removeAttribute("url_prior_login");
                    getRedirectStrategy().sendRedirect(request, response, redirectUrl);
                } else {
                    super.onAuthenticationSuccess(request, response, authentication);
                }
            } else {
                super.onAuthenticationSuccess(request, response, authentication);
            }

            return;
        }

        String targetUrlParameter = getTargetUrlParameter();
        if (isAlwaysUseDefaultTargetUrl()
                || (targetUrlParameter != null && StringUtils.hasText(request.getParameter(targetUrlParameter)))) {
            requestCache.removeRequest(request, response);
            super.onAuthenticationSuccess(request, response, authentication);

            return;
        }

        clearAuthenticationAttributes(request);

        // Use the DefaultSavedRequest URL
        String targetUrl = savedRequest.getRedirectUrl();
        logger.debug("Redirecting to DefaultSavedRequest Url: " + targetUrl);
        getRedirectStrategy().sendRedirect(request, response, targetUrl);
    }
}
```

Also, you don't want to save the referrer when authentication has failed, since the referrer will then be the login page itself. So check for the error param manually or provide a separate RequestMapping like below.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/login", params = "error")
public String loginError() {
    // Don't save referrer here!
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to redirect to a specific page no matter what the user role is, one can simply use
defaultSucessUrl in the configuration file of Spring.

```
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    
    
      http.authorizeRequests() 
      .antMatchers("/admin").hasRole("ADMIN") 
      .and()
      .formLogin() .loginPage("/login") 
                    .defaultSuccessUrl("/admin",true)
      .loginProcessingUrl("/authenticateTheUser")
      .permitAll();
```

Comment: You only set the default one. And everyone is not an admin with admin role. By default, I will set the less privileged role. Logic is preferably implemented in a custom LoginSuccessHandler.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution is to add the success handler that extends `SimpleUrlAuthenticationSuccessHandler` as an anonymous class and calls `setUseReferer(true)` in its initialization block.

```java
    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        return http
                //...
                .formLogin(
                        cfg -> cfg
                                .loginPage("/login")
                                .successHandler(new SimpleUrlAuthenticationSuccessHandler() {{
                                    setUseReferer(true);
                                }})
                )

                .logout(cfg -> cfg.logoutSuccessHandler((request, response, authentication) ->
                        response.sendRedirect(request.getHeader("Referer")))
                )
                //...

                .build();
    }
```