# Keep same URL after login Spring security

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

i want to stay in the same page after login but spring oblige u to redirect to `defaultSuccessUrl`
my code is like this

```
@Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
            .csrf().disable()
            .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/css/**","/fonts/**","/js/**","/app/**","/images/**","/partials/**").permitAll()
                .anyRequest()
                    .authenticated()
        .and()
            .formLogin()
                .loginPage("/login")
                    .defaultSuccessUrl("/index.html")
                    .failureUrl("/login?error=true")
                    .permitAll()
                    .and().logout().logoutSuccessUrl("/login?logout")
                    .and().exceptionHandling().accessDeniedPage("/pages/303.html");

    }
```

Comment: did you solve it

Answer (score 0):

Set

**always-use-default-target="true"**

which will force spring-security to go to /index.html

Comment: it's forbidden to set it with true

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14573654/spring-security-redirect-to-previous-page-after-succesful-login                                                                           This Link May help you according to your problem :)

Comment: did u try `.loginPage("/login")
                    .defaultSuccessUrl("/login")` ??

Answer (score 0):

I think you should add an authentication success handler

```
    @Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
   SavedRequestAwareAuthenticationSuccessHandler successHandler = new    SavedRequestAwareAuthenticationSuccessHandler();
   successHandler.setUseReferer(true);//redirect to the previous page
    http
        .csrf().disable()
        .authorizeRequests()
        .antMatchers("/css/**","/fonts/**","/js/**","/app/**","/images/**","/partials/**").permitAll()
            .anyRequest()
                .authenticated()
    .and()
        .formLogin()
            .loginPage("/login")
                .defaultSuccessUrl("/index.html")
                .failureUrl("/login?error=true")
                .permitAll()
                .successHandler(successHandler)//enable success handler
                .and().logout().logoutSuccessUrl("/login?logout")
                .and().exceptionHandling().accessDeniedPage("/pages/303.html");

}
```

Comment: What is the URL you entered?

Comment: Is it a single page application? I can notice the "#" in the URL

Comment: yes, i am working with angularjs, so when i click on url i include a template page in the same page