# Redirect user to last page due to session expired

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

I want to redirect users to the last visited page if session expired due to long interval.

However, I got the URL through referrer attribute and also from front-end js file I send to the controller but still the controller is not able to redirect the request to the last visited url. Instead, it always redirects to the default URL: Login.js

---

```
var comesFromUrl  = document.referrer,
                    mySiteDomain = document.domain;
                    last_location = comesFromUrl,
                        current_location = document.URL;

                    // Check if cookie exists and if its value is not the current location
                    if(typeof last_location !== "undefined"
                       && last_location !== current_location) {
                        // Here is possible to choose if remove the cookie or refresh it. It's up to you.

                        window.location.href = last_location;
                    }


                    this.sendNotification( publicLogin.ApplicationFacade.LOGIN_SUCCESS);
```

### This is my successhandler  class.

```
public void onAuthenticationSuccess(HttpServletRequest request,
            HttpServletResponse response, Authentication authentication)
            throws IOException, ServletException {
response.setHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache,no-store,must-revalidate");
        response.setHeader("Pragma", "no-cache");
        response.setDateHeader("Expires", -1);
        Object obj = authentication.getDetails();
        if (obj instanceof PublicUserInfo) {
            PublicUserInfo objUser = (PublicUserInfo) obj;

            String cookieData = "userId|~~~" + objUser.getGuid() + "|~~~|instituteId|~~~" + objUser.getInstitutionId();

            Cookie ck= new Cookie("user_info", cookieData);

            ck.setPath("/");
            response.addCookie(ck);
}
```

### This is my controller class

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET, value = "/userlogin/iscaptcharequired.json")
    public ModelAndView isCaptchaRequired(HttpServletRequest objServletRequest,
            HttpServletResponse objServletRespose) {
        // Setting response header to tell client browser not to cache anything.
        objServletRespose.setHeader("Cache-Control",
                "no-cache,no-store,must-revalidate");
        objServletRespose.setHeader("Pragma", "no-cache");
        objServletRespose.setDateHeader("Expires", -1);
        String referrer = objServletRequest.getHeader("Referer");

            objServletRequest.getSession().setAttribute("url_prior_login", referrer);
}
```

### This is my security-config.xml file

```
<sec:filter-chain pattern="/service/**"
                filters="publicSecurityContextPersistenceFilter, 
                    concurrentSessionFilter,
                    publicLogoutFilter,
                    SSOAutoLoginGatewayFilter, 
                    myNePublicUserNamePasswordAuthFilter, 
                    publicAnonymousFilter, 
                    publicExceptionTranslationFilter, 
                    publicFilterSecurityInterceptor" />
<bean id="myNePublicUserNamePasswordAuthFilter"
        class="com.ne.mynelson.authentication.publicuser.MyNePublicUserPasswordAuthFilter">
        <property name="filterProcessesUrl" value="/service/json_authentication_check"></property>
        <property name="authenticationManager" ref="myNePublicUserAuthenticationManager" />
        <property name="authenticationFailureHandler" ref="failureHandler" />
        <property name="authenticationSuccessHandler" ref="successHandler" />
        <property name="authenticationInputProcessor" ref="myNePublicUserAuthInputProcessor"></property>
    </bean>
<bean id="successHandler"
        class="com.ne.mynelson.authentication.publicuser.MyNePublicUserAuthSuccessHandler">
        <property name="authHandlerView" ref="authHandlerView"></property>
        <property name="sessionRegistry" ref="sessionRegistry"></property>
        <property name="publicLoginManager" ref="publicLoginManager"></property>
    </bean>
<bean id="concurrentSessionFilter" class="com.magic.spring.security.ConcurrentSessionFilter">
        <property name="sessionRegistry">
            <ref bean="sessionRegistry" />
        </property>
        <property name="expiredUrl" value="/webapp/staticcontent/html/PublicLogin.html" />
        <property name="logoutHandlers">
            <list>
                <ref bean="publicUserSessionCleanupLogoutHandler" />
                <ref bean="rememberMeServices" /> 
                <ref bean="publicSecurityContextLogoutHandler" />
            </list>
        </property>
    </bean>
```

Answer (score 1):

Add to your spring-security.xml somthing like this

```
<sec:session-management invalid-session-url="/login">
        <sec:concurrency-control expired-url="/expired-page-url" />
</sec:session-management>
```

UPDATE:

Read this 
[Spring Security redirect to previous page after successful login](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14573654/spring-security-redirect-to-previous-page-after-succesful-login)

You need SavedRequestAwareAuthenticationSuccessHandler

From javadoc

```
 * An authentication success strategy which can make use of the
 * {@link org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.DefaultSavedRequest} which may have been stored in the session by the
 * {@link ExceptionTranslationFilter}. When such a request is intercepted and requires
 * authentication, the request data is stored to record the original destination before
 * the authentication process commenced, and to allow the request to be reconstructed when
 * a redirect to the same URL occurs. This class is responsible for performing the
 * redirect to the original URL if appropriate.
```

Comment: Hi i add the security-config.xml file.

Comment: i want if user is automatically loggedout due to session expired then when he again login then he will be redirect to last visited page not to the default home page.

Comment: Hi i am using rest based authentication with concurrentsessionfilter.i tried with SavedRequestAwareAuthenticationSuccessHandler but no good luck.