# Spring Boot Redirect to requested URL after login

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, url-routing

I have a Spring Boot UI application. I am trying to redirect users to the originally requested URL after login.

When a user requests http://www.example.com/myapp/user/22, the application aptly redirects to http://www.example.com/myapp/login. Once the user logs in, the application redirects to http://www.example.com/myapp/dashboard. I would like the application to redirect to http://www.example.com/myapp/user/22.

I have gone through several links and feel I have a proper configuration, yet, redirection is not working as expected.

My Security Config is

```
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
.....
....

    @Autowired
    private MyAuthenticationSuccessHandler authenticationSuccessHandler;

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.
        authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/user/**").authenticated()
                .and().csrf().disable().formLogin()
                .successHandler(authenticationSuccessHandler)
......
```

and My Success Handler is

```
    @Component
    public class MyAuthenticationSuccessHandler extends SimpleUrlAuthenticationSuccessHandler {
    ...
public MyAuthenticationSuccessHandler() {
        super();
        this.setDefaultTargetUrl("/myapp/dashboard");
        this.setUseReferer(true);
    }

        @Override
        public void onAuthenticationSuccess(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response,
                Authentication authentication) throws IOException, ServletException {
            //Do something ..........
            ........
            .........
            super.onAuthenticationSuccess(request, response, authentication);
}
```

I tried using SavedRequestAwareAuthenticationSuccessHandler too.

I notice that my success handler is invoked, but the target URL is always /user/login and my login controller is invoked..

```
@RequestMapping("/login")
public ModelAndView login(@ModelAttribute() {
    if(!userIdentified) {
        //go to login page
    } else {
        new ModelAndView("redirect:/myapp/dashboard");
    }
}
```

and the user is redirected to "dashboard".

What else am I missing?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use "Referer" from session attribute to get the latest request URL. On my app, i use this one

```
public class CustomAuthenticationSuccessHandler extends SimpleUrlAuthenticationSuccessHandler {

    public static final String REDIRECT_URL_SESSION_ATTRIBUTE_NAME = "REDIRECT_URL";

    @Override
    public void onAuthenticationSuccess(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response,
            Authentication authentication) throws IOException, ServletException {

        Object redirectURLObject = request.getSession().getAttribute(REDIRECT_URL_SESSION_ATTRIBUTE_NAME);

        if(redirectURLObject != null)
            setDefaultTargetUrl(redirectURLObject.toString());
        else{
            setDefaultTargetUrl("/");
        }

        request.getSession().removeAttribute(REDIRECT_URL_SESSION_ATTRIBUTE_NAME);
        super.onAuthenticationSuccess(request, response, authentication);
    }

}
```

Edit :

Sorry i forgot to show the login controller

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET, value = {"/login"})
    String login(Model model, Principal principal, HttpServletRequest request) throws Exception{
        String referer = request.getHeader("Referer"); //Get previous URL before call '/login'

        //save referer URL to session, for later use on CustomAuthenticationSuccesshandler
        request.getSession().setAttribute(CustomAuthenticationSuccessHandler.REDIRECT_URL_SESSION_ATTRIBUTE_NAME, referer); 


        return principal == null ?  "login" : "redirect:/"; 
    }
```

Comment: Hmmm......the redirect url object is always null. Am I missing some other configuration? How/Where is that attribute set?

Comment: Sorry, just updated the answer, let me know if it works

Comment: The Referer is also null :( Failure URL is triggered... .failureUrl("/myapp/login?error=true") and I'm guessing that's how the /login is called.

Comment: Mine works well, maybe its just missing security config. Check out [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14573654/spring-security-redirect-to-previous-page-after-successful-login) and [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Referer)

Comment: Argh!!! Figured out the issue. We have an ExceptionResolver with @ExceptionHandler(AccessDeniedException.class) annotated method which redirected to /myapp/login. Hence, I was getting a 302 redirect which set referer to /login. Now, I set the referer in session in this method, and  used it in MyAuthenticationSuccessHandler to redirect. I also did this.setUseReferer(false); Everything working as expected now. Thanks Singgih.

Comment: For me, the referrer is returning the last browsed page, not the secured page which the user requested. And after login, I am redirected to the last browsed page. Am I missing anything? how I could set the referrer to the requested page?

Answer (score 3):

Although [Singgih S](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9687067/singgih-s) answer works, **BUT** there is a better way as below : 
Ref:
https://www.baeldung.com/spring-security-redirect-login

> There is no magic in these easy to use features in Spring Security.
>   When a secured resource is being requested, the request will be
>   filtered by a chain of various filters. Authentication principals and
>   permissions will be checked. If the request session is not
>   authenticated yet, AuthenticationException will be thrown.
>
> The AuthenticationException will be caught in the
>   ExceptionTranslationFilter, in which an authentication process will be
>   commenced, resulting in a redirection to the login page.

Therefore :
1. When redirection to the "/login" page occurs, your secured request url is saved in the session as **`DefaultSavedRequest`** object.
2. Also we know when a successful form based login occurs, one of the implementations of **`AuthenticationSuccessHandler`** is called.
so we can create a custom class and get **`DefaultSavedRequest`** in it as below :

```
public class CustomAuthenticationSuccessHandler extends SimpleUrlAuthenticationSuccessHandler {


    @Override
    public void onAuthenticationSuccess(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Authentication authentication) throws IOException, ServletException {
        DefaultSavedRequest defaultSavedRequest = (DefaultSavedRequest) request.getSession().getAttribute("SPRING_SECURITY_SAVED_REQUEST");
        if(defaultSavedRequest != null){
            getRedirectStrategy().sendRedirect(request, response, defaultSavedRequest.getRedirectUrl());
        }else{
            super.onAuthenticationSuccess(request, response, authentication);
        }
    }
}
```

3. We have to introduce this class in WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter :

```
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.(...).anyRequest().authenticated().and()
                        .formLogin()
                        .loginPage("/login")
                        .loginProcessingUrl("/login")
                        .successHandler(new CustomAuthenticationSuccessHandler());
```

So you can implement your logic in the above **`onAuthenticationSuccess`** method.
Best wishes

Answer (score 0):

The Spring route, ala extending `SavedRequestAwareAuthenticationSuccessHandler` or `SimpleUrlAuthenticationSuccessHandler` can be a bit clunky to implement. In the controller (ex. a POST method that processes logins), you can do the header request yourself; ex:

`HttpServletRequest request =null;`

`String priorUrl = request.getHeader("Referer");`

You will notice that you will have the URL prior to either a manual (initiated by user) logout or a session timeout (as handled by Spring session): you'll get an  `https://iAmPriorUrl.com/...`. Then you can do whatever you want with it.